# textbox autoresizing in actionscript3

Tags: actionscript-3, textbox, adobe, flash-cs3, autoresize

I need to realize textbox autoresizing in actionscript3(IDE - adobe flash pro cs3). For example my textarea is in width 100 px, user has been wrote in it something, that is bigger than 100 px, then my textbox should become increasingly. any ideas?

Also I can't realize multiline option: when the text goes beyond the textbox, it starts to scroll. In line type I've chosen 'multiline'.

thanks

Comment: are you using the TextArea component from the Components Panel or a TextField/the Text Tool ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
textfield.autoSize = "left";
textfield.multiline = true;
textfield.wordWrap = true;
```

Hope it helps,
Rob

Answer (score 1):

If you want to resize textfield automaticaly you can use `textfield.autoSize` property.

Wnen you are using multiline textfield, then setting

```
textfield.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
```

will align text to left and resize field vertically. If you use single line text field, it will resize to the right.

Answer (score 0):

The `TextField`'s `.autosize` property is great for sizing dynamic text fields when you already know the text string (but mind the `.multiline` and `.wordwrap` properties), but won't be helpful for input text fields.

For input text, I'd suggest listening for the `Event.CHANGE` event, then updating the width/height based on the number of lines, the `.textWidth`, or `TextLineMetrics` info (e.g. `myTextField.getLineMetrics`).

Here's a quick example:

```
var myField:TextField = new TextField();
myField.x = 10;
myField.y = 10;
myField.width = 100;
myField.height = 20;
myField.border = true;
myField.type = TextFieldType.INPUT;
myField.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, textChangeHandler);
addChild(myField);

function textChangeHandler(evt:Event) {
    var buffer:Number = 10;
    myField.width = Math.max(100, (myField.textWidth + buffer));
    myField.scrollH = 0;
}
```

**Edit:** Oh, and if you want that to work with `.multiline`, then just add:

```
myField.multiline = true;
```

and in the `textChangeHandler` function add:

```
myField.height = myField.textHeight + buffer;
```